# Parsing every fifth expression in every block

Tags: php, regex

How I can parse in php each fifth expression with class 'StockItem' in every block with class 'evenRowIndxView'?

Source html have several 'block' with class 'evenRowIndxView':

> ```
> <tr class="evenRowIndxView"   onclick="document.location = 'wmquerysnew.asp?refID=12105397&deststamp=59'">
>
>   <td class="StockItem"    align='center'   >12105397</td>
>   <td class="StockItem"  nowrap  align='right'   >100,00</td>
>   <td class="StockItem"  nowrap  align='right'   >3268,00</td>
>   <td class="StockItem"  nowrap  align='right'   >0,0305</td>
>   <td class="StockItem"  nowrap  align='right'   >32,6800 ( +1,37%)</td>
>   <td class="StockItem"  nowrap  align='right'   >199,5</td>
>   <td class="StockItem"  nowrap  align='right'   >6519,64</td>
>   <td class="StockItem"  nowrap  align='right'   >08.06.2013 12:11:36</td>
>
> </tr>
>
> <tr class="oddRowIndxView"   onclick="document.location = 'wmquerysnew.asp?refID=12105391&deststamp=57'">
>
>   <td class="StockItem"    align='center'   >12105391</td>
>   <td class="StockItem"  nowrap  align='right'   >90,85</td>
>   <td class="StockItem"  nowrap  align='right'   >2968,96</td>
>   <td class="StockItem"  nowrap  align='right'   >0,0305</td>
>   <td class="StockItem"  nowrap  align='right'   >32,6798 ( +1,37%)</td>
>   <td class="StockItem"  nowrap  align='right'   >99,5</td>
>   <td class="StockItem"  nowrap  align='right'   >3251,64</td>
>   <td class="StockItem"  nowrap  align='right'   >08.06.2013 12:04:41</td>
>
> </tr>
> ```
>
> etc...

Comment: I parsed every block with class 'evenRowIndxView' and via 'foreach' again parsed every fourth class 'StockItem'. Thus, I got necessary number.

Comment: Regular expressions and context-free languages like HTML do not really mix. You should be using a PHP DOM extension and in the best case an XPath expression to select the values instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there you go a simple and dirty regex solution:

```
if(preg_match_all("/<tr[^>]+evenRowIndxView[^>]+>(\s*<td[^>]+>[^<]+<\/td>\s*){4}\s*<td[^>]+StockItem[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/td>/i", $str, $matches))
{
     //print_r($matches);
    foreach($matches[2] as $match)
    {
        echo $match."<br>";
    }

}
```

should print every 5th row in `evenRowIndxView`, in your given sample it should print:

```
32,6800 ( +1,37%)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to isolate all `evenRowIndxView` blocks. I would use explode

```
$blocks = explode("evenRowIndxView", $html);
```

Now do the same for `StockItem`

```
foreach ($blocks as $block)
{
   $item = explode("StockItem", $block);
   //now your item should be at $item[4]


}
```

Assuming you want just value

```
$str = '<td class="StockItem'.$item[4]; //this put back some HTML so it can be later removed with strip_tags
$value = strip_tags($str);
```

The code above is maybe not 100% accurate, but you should get the idea from it.